# How to test the accuracy of a predictive model?

Tags: confidence-interval, predictive-models, games, bradley-terry-model

I am trying to find the best way to test the accuracy of a predictive model for the outcome of a game between two random teams.  The model presents a chance for each game that team A will win (win chance).  I have gathered almost 3500 samples comparing the win chance with the actual outcome.

As a crude measure I broke down the win chances into bins of 5% increments (or larger where sample size was small).  Within each bin I compared the average win chance with the percentage of games that were won.

Here how I organized my data so far:
[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vOIredJFWq8/Ua-AABHJYPI/AAAAAAAAAMg/DjZHtjaoYbA/w887-h737-no/XVMv-5.jpg]

- "bracket" is the same as bin
- "low-high" is the win chance range for each bin, e.g 20% to 24% chance team A will win, etc
- "games" is number of data points or samples in each bin
- "win loss draw" are the possible outcomes of each sample. I'm mainly focused on the wins
- "my win%" are the observed results of the samples in each bin
- "predicted XVM" is the average win chance of all data points within each bin.

At first glance I would say it's quite accurate, however I would like to have some concrete method or values to show how accurate it is.  I'm guessing breaking it down into bins would be almost like setting confidence (credible?) intervals.  How else to approach this?

Comment: It's fairly standard to break your data set into training and test sets. create your model on the training set (with the win/loss as the class you're trying to predict, then test your model on the test set with the win/loss hidden from you and check the accuracy of the model.  Since you're testing a binomial outcome (win or loss) just checking how many you got right on the test set would serve as a good measure of the predictive value of the model.

Comment: This is actually somebody else's model I am testing.  I am simply gathering data and comparing it to the predictions. As far as "right" or "wrong"  how do you do that?  the model says I have a 60% chance to win.  I can't win 60% of one game, and if I lose the prediction isn't exactly wrong, now is it?  I still had a 40% chance to lose.

i'm assuming this would be much like testing the accuracy of weather forecast, i.e. if the forecast for rain lines up with the number of times it rained given a certain forecast.

Comment: I guess I am already keeping track of how many I got "right" when tracking my win%.  It looks pretty accurate within each bin, but what tests would I use to see just how accurate it is?

Comment: "the model says I have a 60% chance to win. I can't win 60% of one game, and if I lose the prediction isn't exactly wrong, now is it?" In this case, if the model says 60% chance of winning, then you would choose win as your selection (you have to choose win or lose) and if it was lose, then the model would be incorrect.  I'm assuming that this model is being built for some kind of sports forecasting/gambling?  There is no 100% gimme winners or losers in sports.  Everything is a matter of probability.  So if the model says 80% to win, and that teams loses, yes the model was wrong.

Comment: In this case, with the way that your model is assigning percentages, would it make sense to rank the games, i.e. to say that if the model says 90% to win, giving that more weight than one that is only 60% to win?  Does the model seem to get the wins/losses correct more often when the model seems more sure about the outcome?

Comment: it's for a video game. nothing super important. The games that are predicted to win 20-25% of the time actually do end up winning ~20-25% of the time. The same holds true for most other ranges except near the extremes <20% or >80%, it is less accurate at the extremes. Each game is a random collection of players. Actual results tend to cluster in a gaussian curve around 50%. The extreme predictions and results are the exception If you can see the table I posted it shows how I broke down the predictions into smaller ranges of 5% increments. Is this method of analysis proper? I would think so, bu

Comment: pjt, please merge your multiple accounts: http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge. This will enable you to edit and comment on all your questions.